# Is it necessary to close an accept return file descriptor

Tags: linux, sockets

## Just as the title saying,in a tcp connect example

1. a server create a sockfd with `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)` function,
2. then it `bind` the sockfd to a local sockaddr struct,
3. the server `accept` the client's connection, and returns a clientfd
4. server and client `send` or `recv` messages

here is the question,after step 4, is it necessary to close the clientfd by manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned `clientfd` is a brand new file descriptor. If you don't `close` it, that file descriptor will leak.

So, yes, you should *always* `close` the returned file descriptor from `accept`. Note that `shutdown` does not close the file descriptor, it merely prevents it from being used for further communication.